# Is there a way to display multiple colors in a data bar?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tablix which has a data bar in it that I would like to have displayed in different colors. Is there a way to do this without the need to use an IIF or Switch function?

The reason why I ask is because I do not have anything that I can use for a condition. Below is my query in sql to give you an idea of what I'm working with:

```
DECLARE @DTempStart DATETIME, @DTempEnd DATETIME

SET @DTempStart = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @DateFrom)-3, 0)
SET @DTempEnd = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @DateFrom)-1, -1)

SELECT
    DATEPART(year, DateDue) AS YearNum,
    DATEPART(month, DateDue) AS MonthNum,
    DATENAME(month, DateDue) AS 'MonthName',
    COUNT(SiteAudit.SiteAuditID) AS 'Total'
FROM 
    SiteAudit
WHERE
    DateDue BETWEEN @DTempStart AND @DTempEnd AND
    Active = 1 AND
    IsComplete = 1
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(year, DateDue),
    DATEPART(month, DateDue),
    DATENAME(month, DateDue)
ORDER BY
    YearNum,
    MonthNum
```

If anyone could please help I would much appreciate it.

Comment: I was thinking of displaying a row number and the using that as my condition for an IIF function but not sure how I would write it into my query.

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER() function to get the row numbers if you want.

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATEPART(year, DueDate),DATEPART(month, DueDate) ASC)

Comment: what's the logic that drives the change of color? is it one databar or many?

Comment: I ended up using row number as only 3 rows will be returned. I then used a switch function where if row_number = 1 display this color and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way without IIF, Switch or Choose, but you can use any field as a condition. You mention you might need a row number but in that case the row number will be given by an order on fields that can be returned by your query, so why not use those fields directly?
In any case, if you want row number you always have the RowNumber function on ssrs:

```
RowNumber("DataSetName")
```

Comment: You could splice `RowNumber()` into a hex colour value to get a gradient effect, so long as don't have too many rows. `="#" & Hex(RowNumber("DataSet1")) & "0" & Hex(RowNumber("DataSet1")) & "0ff"`

Comment: I ended up using row_number just to have something to use with a switch statement. Thank you for the help!